# Hide root node in sitemap menu

Tags: asp.net

I want to exclude the root node in the sitemap. In this case it's the "Home" node. Here is the sitemap code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~" title="Home" description="Home" roles="*">
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Admin"  description="Admin" roles="admin" >
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Users.aspx" title="All Users"  description="All Users" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin/User.aspx" title="Create User"  description="Create User"  />
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin/CustomerList.aspx" title="All Customers"  description="All Customers" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Customer.aspx" title="Create Customer"  description="Create Customer" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin/Items.aspx" title="Items"  description="Items" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Orders" description="Orders" roles="admin, user">
      <siteMapNode url="~/orders/Default.aspx" title="All Orders" description="All Orders" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/orders/Default.aspx?type=standing" title="Standing" description="Standing" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/orders/Order.aspx" title="New Order" description="New Order" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/orders/Order.aspx?standing=true" title="New Standing" description="New Standing" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

here is the menu and datasource:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
</asp:Menu>

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" StartingNodeOffset="0"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ShowStartingNode="False" />
```

Comment: what it does is, that it makes all the child menu items shown as adjacent to their parents when the menu is rendered. In some cases, this answer doesnt serve.